# "J'aime bien" and "j'aime beaucoup"

Tags: sens, verbes

What's the difference between these expressions?

> J'aime bien
>
> J'aime beaucoup

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated by **oli**, one has a stronger meaning than the other.

“*J'aime beaucoup* ” can be translated by “I like very much” whereas “*J'aime bien* ” will be translated by “I like”.

“*J'adore* ” is an even stronger form than “*J'aime beaucoup* ” and will be translated by “I love” (without love-between-two-persons connotation).

Comment: Est-ce qu'on utilise le verbe "adorer" pour personne ou il est seulment pour des choses ?

Comment: @unepersonne: On peut tout à fait utiliser le verbe « adorer » avec des personnes.

Comment: @ Otiel: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 6):

"J'aime beaucoup" is stronger than "j'aime bien".